# Не загружаются ресурсы сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5, github-pages

Пишу сайт в Visual Studio Code. Во время использования Live Server все ресурсы отображаются нормально[image: введите сюда описание изображения], но когда просто открываю файл index.html картинки не загружаются и немного съезжают стили [image: введите сюда описание изображения], тоже самое и когда выложил сайт на [github pages](https://onskrer.github.io/YIStroi/). Подскажите в чем проблема и как исправить

Comment: Проверяйте файлы в папке "/assets/img" (например, https://onskrer.github.io/assets/img/background.jpg)

Comment: с файлами все в порядке и пути к ним тоже правильные.

Comment: Проблема таки с путями. Сайт ищет картинки по пути https://onskrer.github.io/assets/img/picturePrice2.jpg а находятся они здесь https://onskrer.github.io/YIStroi/assets/img/picturePrice2.jpg. Вот так работает background-image: url(../img/picturePrice2.jpg);